# Calculate the volume of $\iiint (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2dB$ while $B$ is a sphere with radius $2$ with its center in the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

> Calculate the volume of $\iiint (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\,dB$ while $B$ is a sphere with radius $2$ with its center in the origin.

---

I have the solution in the book, they did it the obvious way using sphere coordinates which is something I know how to do but I am simply trying to learn as many ways as possible.

what I tried is $B: x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ then divided by $4$ to try and get the sphere with radius $1$ and set $u= \frac{x}{2}$ $v= \frac{y}{2}$ $w= \frac{z}{2}$ and the jacobian would be $J^{-1}=8$
so now the integral looks like $8 \cdot 4 \iiint(u^2+v^2+w^2)^2\,dV$ but I keep getting wrong answer in the ways I try from here for example if now I move to sphere coordinates and calculate
$$\iiint r^6 \cdot \sin \phi\, dr\,d\phi \,d\theta\,,\text{ while }\quad 0 \leq r \leq 1\,,\quad 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi\,, \quad 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$$
I get a wrong answer.

if I put $u^2+v^2+w^2=1$ and then just calculate the sphere volume using $\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ I also get the wrong answer.

how can I make this way work if it is possible(although it does not really help in this case but just practicing the change of variables and such..)? the correct anwer is $\frac{512 \pi}{ 7}\,.$

Comment: Hint: what is $\int_0^2r^6dr$? What is $\int_0^\pi\sin\phi d\phi\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta$? (By the way, in my experience people label those angles the other way round.)

Comment: I did not know that , in the book they used the angles the way I did but thanks for that!
the first integral is $\frac{128}{7}$ the second $2$ and thirs is $2\pi$ when i multiply it should be correct this way.

I am trying to understand why when I moved to other variables it is not working? didnt the radius change as well and become from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: No, the problem said it's a radius-$2$ sphere.

Comment: @J.G. thank you , so using change of variables and calculating jacobian would not work here

Comment: Well, that's what you're actually doing when you write it as an $r^6dr\sin\phi d\phi d\theta$ integral. The problem seems to be in your understanding of how the limits on $r$ depend on the stated integration range.

Comment: @J.G. The [notational conventions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117234/coordinates-notation-in-spherical-polar-system) for spherical polar coordinates remind one of the east-coast / west-coast metric in special and general relativity. If I get it right: OP's convention is the one that became custom in the 1960ies in American text books "in order to not confuse students by changing the meaning of the Greek letter $\theta$ in the transition from 2D to 3D polar coordinates." Not sure if that was such a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you think, that factor before integral is $8\cdot 4$, while it should be $8\cdot 2^4 = 2^7$:

$8$ comes, as you correctly calculated, from jacobian and $2^4$ from  $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = 2^4 (u^2+v^2+w^2)^2$

After changing variables your integral is $\frac{4\pi}{7}$, so difference between initial one and last exactly is $128=2^7$ and we can be calm about the operation of variable substitution - it works.